# calculate the correlation between two columns in pandas for each pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 affecting VA  affected VB
  A        3   B       -1
  A        4   B        1
  B        10  A         2
  B        7   A        -2
```

for each pair of affecting and affected i want to calculate correlation coefficient and P value ( using scipy.stats.pearsonr ) between VA and VB.

resulting dataframe will be something like :

```
 affecting  affected correlation_coefficient  P_value
   A           B           ...                  ...
   B           A           ...                  ...

 def calc_coefficient ( a, b):
     cor_coef = scipy.stats.pearsonr(a, b)[0]
     Pvalue = scipy.stats.pearsonr(a, b)[1]
     return pd.Series(dict(correlation_coef=cor_coef, P_value=Pvalue))

 uplifts.groupby(["affecting_product","affected_product"])[["UpliftA","UpliftB"]].apply(calc_coefficient)
```

this solution not working and returns : calc_coefficient() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'

Comment: have you tried `groupby(['affecting', 'affected']).apply(pd.corr)` or something like this?

Comment: Forgot to mention that i want to use scipy.stats.pearsonr

Comment: groupby(['affecting', 'affected']).apply(pd.corr) returns module 'pandas' has no attribute 'corr'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `x` for all groups columns and for `a,b` use Series `x['VA'], x['VB']`:

```
def calc_coefficient(x):
    Pvalue, cor_coef = scipy.stats.pearsonr(x['VA'], x['VB'])
    return pd.Series(dict(correlation_coef=cor_coef, P_value=Pvalue))

mask = df.duplicated(subset=["affecting","affected"], keep=False)
df1 = df[mask].groupby(["affecting","affected"]).apply(calc_coefficient)

print (df1)
                    correlation_coef  P_value
affecting affected                           
A         B                      1.0      1.0
B         A                      1.0      1.0
```

Comment: for this specific example it works but in my real problem it is not working apparently because sometimes there is only one row for affecting and affected combination and for scipy.stats.pearsonr(x['VA'], x['VB']) length of x and y should be at least  2

Comment: changing the correlation function or does it even make sense to calculate correlation only between two values not vectors?

Comment: @chessosapiens - Is possible filter only duplciated rows? Like in edited answer?

Comment: i get this error for the new answer : duplicated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'susbet'

Comment: @chessosapiens - oops, my typo `subset` is correct